# How to get this Vue script to work same way on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, vue.js

I read on StackOverflow how to make a hover effect to work in Vue, but it does not work the same way on a mobile device, namely an iPhone

Here's the code:

```
<template>
<div>
  <span id="app">
    <img src="@/assets/london.jpg" width="298px" 
    height="234px">
  </span>
  <span @mouseover="hover = true"
                @mouseleave="hover = false">  
    N
  </span>
 <span id="pos" v-if="hover"><img src="@/assets/anc.jpg" width="4px"
 height="4px"></span>
 <span id="posb" v-if="hover"><img src="@/assets/anc.jpg" width="4px"
 height="4px"></span>
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default{
  data(){
    return{
      hover: false
    }
  }
}
```

(tested on Chrome developer tools, iPhone mode - does that work the same way as a mobile device?)

Any one to point me in right direction? Am I to use Objective-C/ Swift?

Comment: There is not a mouse cursor on mobile devices so you may use another specially events for touchscreens (as tap, double-tab...)

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-touch-events for example

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work on an .html file?